# Programmaticly follow a site, but recieving a error

Tags: 2013, aspx, following

I have a method in my aspx.cs file that should make sure that current user follow the current site. When I check ULS I receive this:

> FollowedContent.FollowItem:Exception:Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException:
>   The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your
>   Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The security validation
>   for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the
>   page, and try your operation
>   again.0x8102006d
>
> Could not follow the url `http://removedlink/`

and

> Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFollowingManager.Follow:
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContentException:
>   InternalError : Could not follow the item
>   X    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContent.FollowItem(FollowedItem
>   item, Boolean isInternal)

My code looks like this:

```
 protected void ToggleUserFollowSite(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                var spWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
                var currentsite = SPContext.Current.Site;
                var currentUser = spWeb.CurrentUser.LoginName;
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
                    {
                        using (var site = new SPSite(spWeb.Site.ID))
                        {
                            using (var web = site.OpenWeb(spWeb.ID))
                            {


                                SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(currentsite);                                                                      
                                var profile = new UserProfileManager(context);                                    
                                var user = profile.GetUserProfile(currentUser);                                   
                                var followingManager = new SPSocialFollowingManager(user, context);                                    
                                var actorInfo = new SPSocialActorInfo();
                                actorInfo.ActorType = SPSocialActorType.Site;
                                actorInfo.ContentUri = new Uri(web.Url);
                                followingManager.Follow(actorInfo);

                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
```

When I debug this this is the exception I get at .Follow() method:

> {"The operation failed because an internal error occurred. Internal
>   type name:
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContentException.
>   Internal error code: 11."}

Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should only use newly created SPSite and SPWeb instances inside RunWithElevatedPrivileges delegation. Change the following line in your code

`SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(currentsite);`

to this one:

```
SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
```

Another problem is security validation on the page, and you need to call [ValidateFormDigest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.validateformdigest.aspx) method before performing the elevation since your code performs the write operation. So add the following line before SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges in your code:

```
SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();
```

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: I get this error screen "An attempt is made to use an SPWeb object that is closed or removed and is no longer valid."

Comment: getting the same errors before this one